# Facebook SDK Singleton in xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have had the Facebook SDK working in the APPDelegate as instructed by the Facebook tutorial, however I am trying to put in into a singleton method. Every tutorial i've found seems to be for an older version of the SDK, but I have managed success with this one http://indiedevstories.com/2011/08/30/a-facebook-reusable-class/

I'm having 2 problems. This is the first problem, (the second is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070304/facebook-sdk-singleton-in-xcode-auto-login-before-post))

I never seem to be able to get fbdidLogin to be called when returning from the Safari Facebook login and authorize screen. (This worked when using the AppDelegate method).
If I set [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO]; in Facebook.m then it works authorising within the app but i'm puzzled why it won't work as it should.
I've seen many questions asked elsewhere, none with a definitive answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated the singleton class to post scores to Facebook Wall. Check out the new version: http://indiedevstories.com/2012/04/11/facebookscorer-post-highscores-to-users-facebook-wall/

HTH